# Hash has value in array as value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to find a certain value in an array as value in hash. If I simply use `ans.has_value?("car")`, it can only find such value if it is not in an array. But if I use `ans.has_value?(["car"])`, it can only find `true` if there is only one `["car"]`; if there are two or more items in such array as value, it returns `false`. Please advise how to find a value in multiple items of an array?

```
ans=Hash.new
ans["a"]=["car"]
ans["b"]=["scar"]
ans["a"]+=["car"]
puts ans.has_value?(["car"])
puts ans

print "Press ENTER to continue . . ."

gets
```

This outputs:

```
false
{"a"=>["car", "car"], "b"=>["scar"]}
Press ENTER to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
!!ans.detect{|_, value| value.include?('car')}
```

Comment: im looking for return value as true, so yes it is what i needed-------ans.detect{|_, value| value.include?('car')}.last.include?"car"

Comment: @user2301576 I edited my answer slightly.

Comment: awesome, may i ask what is the function of the underscore in |_, value|

Comment: @user2301576 of course. It's the convention to mark that this variable passed to to the block is unused.